# Rendering rails real favicon favicons in haml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, favicon

I'm having trouble getting [Rails Real Favicon](https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/rails_real_favicon) to work in my application and I think the problem is the way I'm trying to display the favicon in the head of the `app/views/layouts/angular.html.haml`, `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`, and `app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml` files. Right now all of them have the line:

`= render '/application/favicon’`

I understand that when using Rails Real Favicon `/application/favicon` isn't a partial (it's a folder filled with the different favicon images), so `render` wouldn't work. Please excuse me for my weak Haml, but I’m not sure how to include that folder in the head of those three haml files. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
This was an issue with Chrome. Favicon generates properly in Firefox and Safari, but for some reason not on Chrome when testing locally, not even after clearing my cache and cookies. Works on Chrome after pushed to staging and production. Thanks all for your help and suggestions.

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator'author speaking. Yes, `application/favicon` is a partial, corresponding to `app/views/application/_favicon.html.erb`. Does this file exist in your app? I never used the plugin with HAML, maybe this is why it doesn't work. Which error do you get when you put the `render` line of your question and you visit your app?

Comment: Check this video is about how to add favicon in ruby on rails app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eIOOBrOTs0&t=7s

Comment: @philippe_b, thanks for replying and for all of your work on the favicon generator. That file does exist in my app, and I wasn't getting an error from those ```render``` lines, which made me realize it was being rendered. I was testing in Chrome, so I tried testing in FireFox and it worked. Not sure why it wasn't working in Chrome, even after clearing my cache and cookies, but all is well now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Great! Thank you @S.Causey!

Answer (score 0):

```
 1.- first go to this site if you need to generate favicon in many
    dimensions: https://www.favicon-generator.org/
 2.- second go to this site and convert html generated in first
    step to haml http://htmltohaml.com/
 3.- third create partial and call it in header of your layout file
```

I am sure that will work.